# PERL structured regex

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I'm familiar with higher level languages with libraries like scala and java, and have few problems understanding regex at a high level, but I've been tasked with trying to parse some logs using perl and regex.

Perl seems straightforward enough, but its not native to me).  The data has some fields which may or may not be wrapped in quotes, and others are space delimited.  Additionally, there is one quote wrapped field which needs to be broken into sub-fields.

Sample Data:

```
"[31/01/2015:00:00:00GMT]" "device" 255.255.255.1 2015-01-31 00:00:00 1231231234 - xxxxxxx SUB\xxxxxxx "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW54; Trident/5.0)" 1.255.255.255 text/htm;%20charset=utf-8 hxxp://www.google.com/path?query&somevar=1&anothervar="DOUBLEQUOTESHERE"&thirdvar=jlk;asdfhlkjahgjkdfgerw 200 OBSERVED "Category1;Category 2" "none" "none" TCP_MSG - 0 99 512 512 www.google.com "GET hxxp://www.google.com/somestring.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fsomesite.banana.com%2Fquery%2Fv=1&somevar=1&fin=0 HTTP/1.1"
"[31/01/2015:00:00:00GMT]" "device" 255.255.255.1 2015-01-31 00:00:00 1231231234 - - - "agent" 1.255.255.123 - - 200 OBSERVED "none" "none" "none" TCP_MSG - - 99 256 128 www.google.com "CONNECT hxxp://www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.0"
```

My desired fields would contain as follows for the first line:

```
[31/01/2015:00:00:00 GMT]
device
255.255.255.1
2015-01-31
00:00:00
1231231234
-
xxxxxxx
SUB\xxxxxxx
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW54; Trident/5.0)
1.255.255.255
text/htm;%20charset=utf-8
hxxp://www.google.com/path?query&somevar=1&anothervar="DOUBLEQUOTESHERE"&thirdvar=jlk;asdfhlkjahgjkdfgerw
200
OBSERVED
Category1;Category 2
none
none
TCP_MSG
-
0
99
512
512
www.google.com
GET hxxp://www.google.com/somestring.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fsomesite.banana.com%2Fquery%2Fv=1&somevar=1&fin=0 HTTP/1.1
```

Ideally, I'd like to break the last field down to:

```
GET
hxxp://www.google.com/somestring.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fsomesite.banana.com%2Fquery%2Fv=1&somevar=1&fin=0
HTTP/1.1
```

Second line:

```
[31/01/2015:00:00:00GMT]
device
255.255.255.1
2015-01-31
00:00:00
1231231234
-
-
-
agent
1.255.255.123
-
-
200
OBSERVED
none
none
none
TCP_MSG
-
-
99
256
128
www.google.com
CONNECT hxxp://www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.0
```

And again, I'd like to break the last field down to:

```
CONNECT
hxxp://www.google.com:443
HTTP/1.0
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. With questions like this, we more or less expect you to show what you got working, and where exactly you are stuck. Also, it would really help if you could trim down your examples, making them easier to read. One last thing: Why does it have to be regex? They're really good for lots of things, but severly limited when it comes to actual parsing.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Thanks for the guidance.  As you pointed out, I'm obviously a newb to this forum, but I'm an even bigger newb at Perl.
I thought regex was the best way to proceed, since I'm familiar with it, and the structure of the data can change from line to line.  I.e. a field which contains quote-wrapping could simply be - on the next line.
The regex I would typically use from a library languate would be pretty simple.  Something like '\"[^\"]*\"|\S+' would do it.  I was hopeful there is something similar in Perl.  My apologies for whatever I've done to offend you.

Comment: That's fine. We're all n00bs at a lot of things. But if you don't show what you got, we literally cannot help. And if we feel like you're not doing the basics of reducing the problem to something that we can read quickly, we may want to spend our precious time helping those who do, so you are really doing yourself a favor by trimming everything down to show exactly the place where you are stuck right now. Ask a new question for the next problem after that.

Comment: I don't feel offended, sorry if anything I wrote made it look like that. `(\"[^"]*\"|[^"]\S*)` should work just fine inside a perl re, but I have no idea if you know how to use them in perl without seeing any of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Perl script that does what you want. I used your first line of data for testing.

```
use English;
use strict;

my $line = '"[31/01/2015:00:00:00GMT]" "device" 255.255.255.1 2015-01-31 00:00:00 1231231234 - xxxxxxx SUB\xxxxxxx "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW54; Trident/5.0)" 1.255.255.255 text/htm;%20charset=utf-8 hxxp://www.google.com/path?query&somevar=1&anothervar="DOUBLEQUOTESHERE"&thirdvar=jlk;asdfhlkjahgjkdfgerw 200 OBSERVED "Category1;Category 2" "none" "none" TCP_MSG - 0 99 512 512 www.google.com "GET hxxp://www.google.com/somestring.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fsomesite.banana.com%2Fquery%2Fv=1&somevar=1&fin=0 HTTP/1.1"';

my @fields;
while ($line ne "")
    {
    if  (($line =~ /^"(?<field>[^"]*)"(\s+|$)/p) or ($line =~ /^(?<field>\S+)(\s+|$)/p))
        {
        push @fields, $+{field};
        $line = ${^POSTMATCH};
        } # if
        else {die "Parse error when line is '$line'\n";}
    } # while

my $last_field = pop @fields;
push @fields, split /\s+/, $last_field;
print join("\n", @fields) . "\n";
exit 0;
```

Things to note:

1. 'use strict;' is very important for catching typos and other silly errors.
2. In the two regular expressions within the while loop, I used named capturing because I think it's more readable to refer to $+{field} than $1.
3. I ended these two regular expressions with /p so I could refer to ${^POSTMATCH} instead of $POSTMATCH. ${^POSTMATCH} is more efficient.
4. If the first regular expression matches $line, the second expression will not be evaluated.

I wrote the code above quickly and it is not industrial strength. For example, the code will fail if the input data begins with a space.

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of question, you can get even this kind of answer

```sh
perl -nlE'my@a;push@a,$+while/\s*(?:"(.*?)"|(\S*))/g;splice@a,-1,1,split/ /,$a[-1];$,=$\;say@a,""' your_log.txt
```

and result

```
[31/01/2015:00:00:00GMT]
device
255.255.255.1
2015-01-31
00:00:00
1231231234
-
xxxxxxx
SUB\xxxxxxx
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW54; Trident/5.0)
1.255.255.255
text/htm;%20charset=utf-8
hxxp://www.google.com/path?query&somevar=1&anothervar="DOUBLEQUOTESHERE"&thirdvar=jlk;asdfhlkjahgjkdfgerw
200
OBSERVED
Category1;Category 2
none
none
TCP_MSG
-
0
99
512
512
www.google.com
GET
hxxp://www.google.com/somestring.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fsomesite.banana.com%2Fquery%2Fv=1&somevar=1&fin=0
HTTP/1.1


[31/01/2015:00:00:00GMT]
device
255.255.255.1
2015-01-31
00:00:00
1231231234
-
-
-
agent
1.255.255.123
-
-
200
OBSERVED
none
none
none
TCP_MSG
-
-
99
256
128
www.google.com
CONNECT
hxxp://www.google.com:443
HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: This is very elegant, and it's probably what Chris meant when he suggested RE might not be the best solution.  I wish I could accept two right answers.  Thank you for your time!